# Can you use a 128 pin LCD on an atMega?

Tags: arduino-mega, lcd, pins

I found a couple old calculators and their LCD's have about 130 pins.

I was wondering if I can build an LCD driver to reduce the number of I/O pins, because I don't want to use like 14 I/O extenders; or can I make 1 huge extender?

Comment: Shift registers might be easier and cheaper as you don't need input capability like with IO extenders

Comment: What kind of LCD is this? Is each pin connected to one segment/pixel, and all of them share the same backplane? Or is this a row-column-matrix? Please keep in mind that you need to apply alternating voltage to LCD because DC will be bad for it.

Comment: It is a 32x96 dotmatrix the entire thing running on 1 1.5v lr44

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes that each LCD segment is controlled by a separate pin (see comment of Juraj).

With a 74HC595 (shift register) you can use SPI to control 8 outputs.
You can daisy chain 4 of them to get 32 outputs with just the SPI pins, to get 128 pins. I assume two pins are for GND and VCC. If you need more than 128 GPIO output pins, than use 5 or more sets of daisy chained shift registers.

Now, since these shift registers use SPI, you can use the slave select to use multiple sets of daisy chained shift registers. I never tried this myself though.

The pins (except GND/VCC) you use is:

- 3 SPI pins (MISO, MOSI, CLK)
- 4 SS pins (one for each set of 4 daisy chained shift registers)

The idea is:

1. Set SS pin to the first set of 4 shift registers
2. Write 32 outputs for the first 32 segment output pins (using the 4 shift registers of the first set)
3. Set SS pin to the next set of 4 shift registers
4. Write 32 outputs for the next set
5. Continue with the next 2 sets (so you can use 32 * 4 = 128 pins)
6. In the next cycle, start with step 1 again

Comment: this assumes that one pin controls one segment on a LCD with digit segments

Comment: @Juraj True, I added it in the answer, thanks. I would think it's otherwise anyway, why would you create a nontrivial protocol and still using 130 pins. And thanks for improving my answer.

Comment: it could be a matrix, but now as I think about it, it doesn't change the answer

Comment: @Juraj That would make a lot of segments possible (having an X-Y matrix). But indeed only the algorithm to fill the pins is more complicated. I expect like e.g. 10 digits * 8 segments = 80 pins, and some extra for the items/words around (since it's an old calculator).

Comment: I see i was thinking of using 8 mcp23017 chips from 2 pins to get to 128 and use 15 for matrix buttons which leaves me 36 pins

Comment: That might also be possible, I don't have used MCP23017s so far. In principle the 74HC595 are typically for adding outputs, however, I found out the 74HC595's can only source 70 mA, so in case of 8 segments you could use e.g. an ULN2803. However, as the busybee has written, you might not be able to use these at all, but a specific LCD IC/driver, since LCD uses AC.